# What may be the difficulties, if any, with the web applications developed in Java EE?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I have a few questions to understand better Java's usage in context of web applications:-

Is Java EE web development suitable for small start-up (*with less human resource*) looking to develop an web application ?

What kind of difficulties may arise in Java EE web development, deployment & maintenance ?

What kind of things should be kept in mind/ considerations to be made when moving from PHP background to Java ?

Why Java web applications are not so popular today?  ( or in case I perceived it wrongly, please list any major deployments beside linkedIn and ebay)

and Finally, What are some of the *most important things to learn before starting* web development in Java EE ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really mean Java EE Webapplications or do you mean Java Web Applications? There is a difference in the complexity.

Comment: I do not know how they are different.. but I am intending a social networking app using Java.

Comment: If you are at expert level in java, means you know nook and corner,when to use what specifically choosing best collection classes,libraries, then go ahead with J2EE.

Comment: no I am beginner(that's why this question) but I can work it out(if that's practically feasible?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to answer these from the perspectives of a developer/architect in a small start-up, experiencing a bunch of these issues.

*What kind of difficulties may arise in Java EE web development, deployment & maintenance ?*

How do you decide on which toolset/framework to use? Do you need an IDE? Which version control system and why? Do you want to develop at some place and deploy somewhere else, or develop directly on the server? Do you buy a linux box for this, or rent some cloud? How much do they cost, in terms of licenses and training?

*What kind of things should be kept in mind/ considerations to be made when moving from PHP background to Java ?*

How would your servlet send out an e-mail? It's much simpler in PHP. Need secure transfer of encrypted objects? Java is your friend. What about session tracking? Use cookies, or have a dedicated class do it? How do you access the database? Want to use hibernate? What other tools is hibernate dependent on? What are their costs (license+learning)? Can you use JDBC directly? What are the pros and cons? Which db to use to why.

*Why Java web applications are not so popular today? ( or in case I perceived it wrongly, please list any major deployments beside linkedIn and ebay)*

I am not sure if this is the case, but possible reasons could be the availability of .net and integration with C# based systems and Apple ditching Java from its SDK. But that is my speculation, don't quote me on it. I am developing a large scale system myself with Java 6.

*and Finally, What are some of the most important things to learn before starting web development in Java EE ?*

(This is my opinion) have a test or trial set up of the entire architecture. Is the GUI web-brower based? Is it an applet? Standalone application talking to a server? JNLP system downloading archives and JRE off the net? You will find some stuff do not work on Windows 7, some do not on Vista, W3C have deprecated the applet tag from HTML but Sun/Oracle asks you to use it, different browsers do not support contents of your style sheet, etc.

Firewall set up is another major challenge - you start using thread pooling using Spring libraries and your capabilities to use DBvisualizer to check on DB tables are gone! Now you need a DBA and a sys-admin to fix these who you do not have!

Personally I found the LAMP architecture (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) the fastest way to go for smaller applications, but if you need heavier guns for your app (security, GUI with swing, multithreading, etc), replace the P in LAMP with a tomcat container. The hardest thing I find is to judge the value of a tool in the context of my application - I do not need a tool that generates Java files with getter/setter methods given a list of variables - to me that is yet another level of indirection, but then JUnit in eclipse is helpful for debugging.

Just shared some of my thoughts - hope this helps, - M.S.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience & writing such a detailed answer! Great answer!

Comment: Is there any difference in the costs of deployment,etc compared to LAMP stack perhaps may be due to any major thing not available open source for Java ?? ALso I heard, I believe they are rumors, that Java web app perform too slow at times.

Comment: @Marcos: What I also found is that availability on open source is not the only criterion - How long can you rely on some library? You train yourself for a library use, and a new release comes out - NOT compatible with earlier versions. Examples: MySQL 4-5, Spring 2.5-2.6, etc. Some of these problems will always stay, but it is your judgment call how much you want your code to be dependent on such libraries. I wanted to use hibernate, couldnt find all the bells and whistles required to use it, and ended up with a homegrown version that I am sure is not as good. Good luck on your search, - M.S.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the answer to the question of "what technology to use" is "the one which you have most experience with". However, Java EE is huge and clunky, and definitely not good for rapid prototyping, which you will be doing if you're doing a startup.

Personally I would recommend a more modern and dynamic environment. If you're coming from PHP, you should be able to pick up Ruby on Rails or Django (Python) easily. These two choices are in my opinion orders of magnitude better than Java EE.  If you want to stick with Java, at least go with the Play framework then.

Comment: If you mean prototyping of the frontend/ GUIs we would be doing that in flash or some other softwares. Are you suggesting these languages based on performance reasons or because they just provide a better way to do things ?

Comment: -1 I worked both in Java web-development and with Rails, and later has its fair share of quirks too.  In short, hot code reloading isn't the only thing that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Is Java EE web development suitable for small start-up (with less human resource) looking to develop an web application ?

Yes, I worked in a startup where I was the only full time programmer.

What kind of difficulties may arise in Java EE web development, deployment & maintenance ?

The same as in any other web development shop. Of course, the problems have their Java flavor. For instance, one bug we discovered was caused by different  minor version of JDK used on the live system than on our test system.

What kind of things should be kept in mind/ considerations to be made when moving from PHP background to Java ? Do not code the PHP way. Java's strength is OOP and its many libraries/ open source frameworks. Use that.

Why Java web applications are not so popular today? ( or in case I perceived it wrongly, please list any major deployments beside linkedIn and ebay)

I don't know why you think that, but Java is used everywhere. It is one of the few languages that Google officially uses. They use PHP as well, but it has a "lower" status.

and Finally, What are some of the most important things to learn before starting web development in Java EE ? Use Java's strong points which I mentioned above.

**Updated after comment**

I cannot make the choice for you. If you are in doubt and in a big hurry you should not go with Java. This is common sense. However, it is an opportunity for your team to learn and grow. Maybe there is a PHP/other client for Cassandra. I knew a former PHP programmer in a startup, who switched to Java. Not saying anything bad about PHP programmers in general, but he did all kinds of strange things, such as not leveraging the power of Java web frameworks and writing lots of procedural code mixed with HTML and SQL. Obviously there are lots of Java programmers who would do the same thing. The point is that your team will probably learn new ways to do things and benefit from it in the future.

Comment: Navi, our project is big(a social networking site) and we are all just beginners to Java web development (but not to Java/OOPs). and we also have cost preferences. Also after hearing several perhaps rumors that java web development/deployment is not easier, it has certainly become a big question for us. and the primary reason we are moving towards java is that we are using Cassandra database using a Java client called Hector. So then in these particular circumstances what do you think, should we take step into java world or better take an easy way for the sake of project completion?

Answer (score 0):

For a startup an interesting choice could be the [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) web framework, which is used for developing "Java Web Applications" (although in Scala).